# If count >= A ......count <= count +1

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write VHDL code for a multiplier which uses repeated addition. This is the code that I've written:

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity FinalProjectDLL is
port (
CLOCK_50, reset : IN std_logic;
A, B : IN std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
pl, ph, A_disp, B_disp: OUT std_logic_vector (6 downto 0));
end FinalProjectDLL;

architecture behavior of FinalProjectDLL is
type state_type is (s1, s2, s3);
signal state : state_type;

constant delay : integer := 100000000000000000;
constant halfdelay : integer :=delay/2;         
signal count_clock : integer range 0 to delay;
signal clock : std_logic;
signal count : integer;
signal in_project_product: integer;
signal Ai : integer;
signal Bi : integer;

begin
Ai <= conv_integer(A);
Bi <= conv_integer(B);

multi_crtl : process (clock, reset)
begin
if(reset = '0') then
count <= 0;
state <= s1;
elsif(clock'event and clock = '1') then
case state is

when s1 =>    
in_project_product <= 0;
state <= s2;

when s2 =>
if count <= Ai then
in_project_product <= in_project_product + Bi;
count <= count + 1; --VERY WORRIED
state <= s2;
else
state <= s3;
end if;

when s3 =>
pl <= conv_std_logic_vector (in_project_product, 7);
ph <= conv_std_logic_vector(in_project_product, 7);
A_disp <= conv_std_logic_vector(Ai, 7);
B_disp <= conv_std_logic_vector(Bi, 7);
state <= s1;

end case;
end if;
end process; 

clock_divide: process
begin 
wait until clock_50'event and clock_50 = '1';
if count_clock < delay then 
count_clock <= count_clock + 1;
else 
count_clock <= 0;
end if;
if count_clock <  halfdelay then
clock <= '0';
else
clock <= '1';
end if;
end process;

end
```

The code compiles, so, I think I've fixed all the syntax bugs. My concern is the following: The code that I'm using has an if loop that is written with the format `if count >= a then`...something happens... `count <= count +1`. Will the value of count increase and run through the if loop until `count = a`, like in C? Will it change in the next clock cycle? I ask because I've been given conflicting answers from my professors and teaching assistants.

If anyone sees anything else in the code that concerns you, please let me know!
Thanks everyone and have a great day!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `count` will increment once per clock cycle, because it is after the line `elsif(clock'event and clock = '1') then` in a sequential process. However, my advice would be to simulate it and see what happens.

Comment: The literal of 100000000000000000 is out of range for most VHDL tools, particularly for synthesis with an INTEGER range of –2147483647 to +2147483647. Maybe you can tell us what this design does?  `delay` represents the ratio of `clock_50` (presumably 50 MHz)  to the `clock`, and 100000000000000000 gives a very slow `clock`. You're missing a semicolon after the final `end` and IEEE package numeric_std is unused and is incompatible with Synopsys packages std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned.  Simulated with [delay=10](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt8jG.png).

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys! It ended up working with slight modifications to the literal as you mentioned above user1155120 (we changed it to 5). We also modified the first state a little.

Matthew, thanks for that clarification. I was really worried that the code might not work due to that.